# Copying a field for every document

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to copy a field into a new field. I thought this would do it for every document in the collection.

```
for m in db.col.find():
    db.col.update(
        m,
        {'$set': {'NameOld': m.get('Name', '')}},
        multi=True)
```

However, when I run

```
db.col.find({'NameOld': {'$exists': false}})
```

there are a number of documents that appear without the `NameOld` field. How is that happening, and how can I make sure it works for every document?

Comment: Well if there are new documents written in the time your update runs then the new docs won't have that property 'NameOld'. If there are no write operations during your update then please share more information, i.e. how do the docs look like, especially the ones which aren't updated. If possible, make an example which reproduces your problem.

Comment: Could be a syntax error . The option multi should be enclosed in parentheses like  { multi: true }

Comment: Do the documents appear without a NameOld field or with an EMPTY NameOld field? Because the m.get('Name','') will fill with empty strings for those docs without the 'Name' field.